# Dealing with program argument and a variable in bash

Tags: bash, variables

I have the following set of shell variables.

```sh
var0=000
var1=111
var2=222
var3=333
```

I want another variable `var` determined by the user's cli arguments `($1)`
during execution to point to one of the above variables (`var0 to var3`).

CLI arguments are passed to the script in the following manner `./script.sh 1`

```sh
# === script.sh ===
k="$1"
var=var$k
echo $var
```

But `$var` is empty in the output.

Comment: please specify if you mean **user input** derived using `read` or **positional arguments** that are at the end of the script's cli call i.e. `script.sh 000` in the terminal. if possible, share the entire script source code.

Comment: Since `k` is set to 1 (in your invocation), `var` has the value `var1` and the echo statement should output the string var1. I don't see any "selection by user input" in your piece of code.

Comment: @user193442, the user input is at the end of the script cli call, like ./script.sh 0

Comment: This is usually not called _user input_, but _passing a program parameter_ or _passing a program argument_, or, as kevinnls said, _positional arguments_. If you talk about user input, we think you want to fiddle with /dev/tty, or at least do a `read` command or something like this.

Comment: i don't see how var can be empty. even if there is some problem with `$k`, `$var` should at least contain the literal `var` could you please share the output you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how var can be empty. Even if there is some problem with `$k`, `$var` should at least contain the literal string `var`.
Could you please share the output you get?

Nonetheless, I assume you are trying to access the value of `$var1` *indirectly* from `$var`, for which the solution is as follows:

```sh
echo "${!var}"
```

**Note:** You need to make sure `$1` is not empty or invalid (string or >3 or <0). Consider using brace expansion to use a default value if `$1` is null - `${1:-'1'}`

#### Explanation

The `${!var}` syntax executes *indirect expansion* in this manner (for the given code)

0. assuming the command was `./script.sh 1`
1. `var` is expanded to its value - `var1`
2. the value of the variable `var1` is expanded to `111`

---

#### Alternative - possibly better

Alternatively, (and perhaps more efficiently) you can use an array as [suggested by @KamilCuk in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67086860/13982210) modifying it to use `${var[$1]}` instead of reading user input.

Comment: Also, you should double-quote variable references (e.g. `echo "${!var}"` instead of just `echo ${!var}`).

Answer (score 2):

Just use an array.

```
var=(000 111 222 333)
read k
echo "${var[k]}"
```

Comment: OP meant to say positional arguments. not user input. please consider modifying your answer appropriately